# How Can I Evaluate This Integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{dx} {x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone help me with this integration question 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx} {x+\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

I tried substitution with x=sinx and also tries times both denominator and numerator by 
$$ x- \sqrt {1-x^2} $$
but it becomes even more complicated. Can someone gives me a hint how to solve this question please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can choose the best answer that works for you by check-marking the answer. Just notice the check-mark sign next to each answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Set $x=\sin y$

Then apply $$I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

$$I+I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Answer (score 3):

This is just another variation on a theme that has been used in other answers, but I think it might be worth seeing in this guise:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}
&=\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{3}\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi4\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2}$
$(2)$: average the left and right sides of $(1)$
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto\sin(\theta)$
$(4)$: integrate

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach gets the denominator to be $x^2 - (1- x^2) = 2x^2 - 1$, and you can split the numerator into two parts, so you have to separate integrals. That's good.

Now do you deal with that denominator? Try $x = u / \sqrt{2}$. Then you can do an sine or cosine substitution (or even secant) substitution.

Answer (score 2):

**First Method**

$1)$ We make subtitution $x = \sin (u)$ and conclude that

$$I = \int _0^{{\pi  \over 2}}{{\cos \left( u \right)} \over {\sin \left( u \right) + \cos \left( u \right)}}\;du\tag{1}$$

$2)$ Next, we use this substitution $u=\pi / 2 - v$ to get

$$I=\int _0^{{\pi  \over 2}}{{\sin \left( v \right)} \over {\cos \left( v \right) + \sin \left( v \right)}}\;dv\tag{2}$$

$3)$ Sum the previous results

$$2I = \int_0^{{\pi  \over 2}} {{{\sin (u) + \cos \left( u \right)} \over {\sin \left( u \right) + \cos \left( u \right)}}du}  = \int_0^{{\pi  \over 2}} {1du}  = {\pi  \over 2}\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,I = {\pi  \over 4}\tag{3}$$

**Second Method**

$1)$ Use the tangent half angle substitution, $u={\tan(\frac{v}{2})}$, in equation $(1)$ to get

$$I=\int _0^\infty {1 \over {\left( {{v^2} + 1} \right)\left( {v + 1}
 \right)}}\;dv\tag{4}$$

$2)$ Use **partial fraction** to decompose the integrand and finally

$$\eqalign{
  & I = {1 \over 2}\int_0^\infty  {\left( {{1 \over {v + 1}} + {{ - v} \over {{v^2} + 1}} + {1 \over {{v^2} + 1}}} \right)dv}   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = \left. {{1 \over 2}\left( {\ln (v + 1) - {1 \over 2}\ln ({v^2} + 1) + \arctan (v)} \right)} \right|_0^\infty   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{v \to \infty } {1 \over 2}\left( {\ln (v + 1) - {1 \over 2}\ln ({v^2} + 1) + \arctan (v)} \right) = {\pi  \over 4} \cr} \tag{5}$$